Add wearable to RFM69 network
My goal is to add a wearable (wristband) to my rfm69 (sx1231) 868MHz network. The network consists of several rfm69 nodes in a star topology in FSK mode. The wearable should notify the user via vibration and display output and look nice (no 3D printed monster case on the wrist).
The problem is that there are watches on the market with integrated LORA chips (SX1261), where it is also possible to develop with them (Lilygo T-Watch S3). But they are not compatible with rfm69, because rfm69 is not lora and uses hw encryption and other differences. I searched for simple solutions, but found nothing satisfying for my purpose.

Here are some of my implementation thoughts

Try to work on lora lilygo t-watch S3 and develop a compatible library for lora to rfm69. (exhausting)

Contact liligo if they produce a variant with rfm69 in it (no success)

Use gateway wifi accesspoint, implement mqtt-broker and publish to wifi smart-watch. (problem with multiple smartwatches)

Checked fiverr to see if someone could make me a professional solution. (not a good fit)

Build my own rfm69 wristband (would look clumsy)

build a gateway addon board with rfm69 and lora chip (adds system complexity)


I've run out of ideas, and perhaps someone here can point me in the direction of a suitable product on the market, or the most elegant solution.

Have you looked into https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib ?

Yes i know that library. But there is no out of the box compatibility library for rfm69 and rfm95 for example. I've read about running lora module in FSK mode like the rfm69, but the problem here is, that the rfm69 uses hw-encryption, while the lora modules not.
